# failed to create local server ( address already in use ) when trying to serve flutter_web project

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

i tried launch the flutter web project locally by this terminal command

```
 webdev serve --auto restart
```

but i got the following error message

```
    Starting resource servers...Unhandled exception:
SocketException: Failed to create server socket (OS Error: Address already in use, errno = 48), address = 127.0.0.1, port = 8080
#0      _NativeSocket.bind (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:591:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
#1      _RawServerSocket.bind (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:1206:26)
#2      _ServerSocket.bind (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:1466:29)
#3      ServerSocket.bind (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:1457:26)
#4      _HttpServer.bind (dart:_http/http_impl.dart:2520:25)
#5      HttpServer.bind (dart:_http:227:19)
#6      HttpMultiServer.loopback.<anonymous closure> (package:http_multi_server/http_multi_server.dart:113:39)
#7      HttpMultiServer._loopback (package:http_multi_server/http_multi_server.dart:172:30)
<asynchronous suspension>
#8      HttpMultiServer.loopback (package:http_multi_server/http_multi_server.dart:111:12)
#9      WebDevServer.start (package:webdev/src/serve/webdev_server.dart:83:33)
#10     _AsyncAwaitCompleter.start (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:49:6)
#11     WebDevServer.start (package:webdev/src/serve/webdev_server.dart:54:36)
#12     ServerManager.start (package:webdev/src/serve/server_manager.dart:22:38)
#13     _AsyncAwaitCompleter.start (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:49:6)
#14     ServerManager.start (package:webdev/src/serve/server_manager.dart:18:37)
#15     _startServerManager (package:webdev/src/serve/dev_workflow.dart:85:27)
#16     _AsyncAwaitCompleter.start (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:49:6)
#17     _startServerManager (package:webdev/src/serve/dev_workflow.dart:66:42)
#18     DevWorkflow.start (package:webdev/src/serve/dev_workflow.dart:186:31)
#19     _RootZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1379:54)
#20     _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:126:18)
#21     Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:639:45)
#22     Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:668:32)
#23     Future._complete (dart:async/future_impl.dart:473:7)
#24     _SyncCompleter.complete (dart:async/future_impl.dart:51:12)
#25     _AsyncAwaitCompleter.complete.<anonymous closure> (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:33:20)
#26     _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:41:21)
#27     _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:50:5)
#28     _runPendingImmediateCallback (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:115:13)
#29     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:172:5)
abdullah@Abdullahs-MacBook-Pro ~/D/F/web_profile> webdev serve --auto restart
[SEVERE] Deleted previous snapshot due to missing asset graph.
[INFO] Building new asset graph completed, took 1.4s
[INFO] Checking for unexpected pre-existing outputs. completed, took 1ms
[INFO] Starting resource servers...Unhandled exception:
SocketException: Failed to create server socket (OS Error: Address already in use, errno = 48), address = 127.0.0.1, port = 8080
#0      _NativeSocket.bind (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:591:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
#1      _RawServerSocket.bind (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:1206:26)
#2      _ServerSocket.bind (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:1466:29)
#3      ServerSocket.bind (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:1457:26)
#4      _HttpServer.bind (dart:_http/http_impl.dart:2520:25)
#5      HttpServer.bind (dart:_http:227:19)
#6      HttpMultiServer.loopback.<anonymous closure> (package:http_multi_server/http_multi_server.dart:113:39)
#7      HttpMultiServer._loopback (package:http_multi_server/http_multi_server.dart:172:30)
<asynchronous suspension>
#8      HttpMultiServer.loopback (package:http_multi_server/http_multi_server.dart:111:12)
#9      WebDevServer.start (package:webdev/src/serve/webdev_server.dart:83:33)
#10     _AsyncAwaitCompleter.start (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:49:6)
#11     WebDevServer.start (package:webdev/src/serve/webdev_server.dart:54:36)
#12     ServerManager.start (package:webdev/src/serve/server_manager.dart:22:38)
#13     _AsyncAwaitCompleter.start (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:49:6)
#14     ServerManager.start (package:webdev/src/serve/server_manager.dart:18:37)
#15     _startServerManager (package:webdev/src/serve/dev_workflow.dart:85:27)
#16     _AsyncAwaitCompleter.start (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:49:6)
#17     _startServerManager (package:webdev/src/serve/dev_workflow.dart:66:42)
#18     DevWorkflow.start (package:webdev/src/serve/dev_workflow.dart:186:31)
#19     _RootZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1379:54)
#20     _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:126:18)
#21     Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:639:45)
#22     Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:668:32)
#23     Future._complete (dart:async/future_impl.dart:473:7)
#24     _SyncCompleter.complete (dart:async/future_impl.dart:51:12)
#25     _AsyncAwaitCompleter.complete.<anonymous closure> (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:33:20)
#26     _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:41:21)
#27     _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:50:5)
#28     _runPendingImmediateCallback (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:115:13)
#29     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:172:5)
abdullah@Abdullahs-MacBook-Pro ~/D/F/web_profile> webdev serve --auto restart
[SEVERE] Deleted previous snapshot due to missing asset graph.
[INFO] Starting resource servers...Unhandled exception:
SocketException: Failed to create server socket (OS Error: Address already in use, errno = 48), address = 127.0.0.1, port = 8080
#0      _NativeSocket.bind (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:591:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
#1      _RawServerSocket.bind (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:1206:26)
#2      _ServerSocket.bind (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:1466:29)
#3      ServerSocket.bind (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:1457:26)
#4      _HttpServer.bind (dart:_http/http_impl.dart:2520:25)
#5      HttpServer.bind (dart:_http:227:19)
#6      HttpMultiServer.loopback.<anonymous closure> (package:http_multi_server/http_multi_server.dart:113:39)
#7      HttpMultiServer._loopback (package:http_multi_server/http_multi_server.dart:172:30)
<asynchronous suspension>
#8      HttpMultiServer.loopback (package:http_multi_server/http_multi_server.dart:111:12)
#9      WebDevServer.start (package:webdev/src/serve/webdev_server.dart:83:33)
#10     _AsyncAwaitCompleter.start (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:49:6)
#11     WebDevServer.start (package:webdev/src/serve/webdev_server.dart:54:36)
#12     ServerManager.start (package:webdev/src/serve/server_manager.dart:22:38)
#13     _AsyncAwaitCompleter.start (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:49:6)
#14     ServerManager.start (package:webdev/src/serve/server_manager.dart:18:37)
#15     _startServerManager (package:webdev/src/serve/dev_workflow.dart:85:27)
#16     _AsyncAwaitCompleter.start (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:49:6)
#17     _startServerManager (package:webdev/src/serve/dev_workflow.dart:66:42)
#18     DevWorkflow.start (package:webdev/src/serve/dev_workflow.dart:186:31)
#19     _RootZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1379:54)
#20     _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:126:18)
#21     Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:639:45)
#22     Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:668:32)
abdullah@Abdullahs-MacBook-Pro ~/D/F/web_profile> webdev serve --auto restart
[SEVERE] Deleted previous snapshot due to missing asset graph.
[INFO] Building new asset graph completed, took 1.3s
[INFO] Checking for unexpected pre-existing outputs. completed, took 1ms
[INFO] Starting resource servers...Unhandled exception:
SocketException: Failed to create server socket (OS Error: Address already in use, errno = 48), address = 127.0.0.1, port = 8080
#0      _NativeSocket.bind (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:591:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
#1      _RawServerSocket.bind (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:1206:26)
#2      _ServerSocket.bind (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:1466:29)
#3      ServerSocket.bind (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:1457:26)
#4      _HttpServer.bind (dart:_http/http_impl.dart:2520:25)
#5      HttpServer.bind (dart:_http:227:19)
#6      HttpMultiServer.loopback.<anonymous closure> (package:http_multi_server/http_multi_server.dart:113:39)
#7      HttpMultiServer._loopback (package:http_multi_server/http_multi_server.dart:172:30)
<asynchronous suspension>
#8      HttpMultiServer.loopback (package:http_multi_server/http_multi_server.dart:111:12)
#9      WebDevServer.start (package:webdev/src/serve/webdev_server.dart:83:33)
#10     _AsyncAwaitCompleter.start (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:49:6)
#11     WebDevServer.start (package:webdev/src/serve/webdev_server.dart:54:36)
#12     ServerManager.start (package:webdev/src/serve/server_manager.dart:22:38)
#13     _AsyncAwaitCompleter.start (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:49:6)
#14     ServerManager.start (package:webdev/src/serve/server_manager.dart:18:37)
#15     _startServerManager (package:webdev/src/serve/dev_workflow.dart:85:27)
#16     _AsyncAwaitCompleter.start (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:49:6)
#17     _startServerManager (package:webdev/src/serve/dev_workflow.dart:66:42)
#18     DevWorkflow.start (package:webdev/src/serve/dev_workflow.dart:186:31)
#19     _RootZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1379:54)
#20     _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:126:18)
#21     Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:639:45)
#22     Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:668:32)
```

my attempts to solve this problem by force quit the dart process from activity monitor , 
but still i get same error

is there anyway to change the port number from 8080 to any ?

or anyway to change to port number automatically if given default port is not available ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Short answer.

```
webdev serve web:8082
```

Where `web` is a directory name and `8082` is a port number.

Comment: i tried the command your mentioned i got the following error 
[SEVERE] Failed to precompile build_runner:build_runner:
[SEVERE] file:///Users/abdullah/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/build_runner-1.6.1/bin/build_runner.dart:8:8: Error: Error when reading 'packages/args/args.dart': No such file or directory
[SEVERE] import 'package:args/args.dart';
[SEVERE]        ^
[SEVERE] file:///Users/abdullah/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/build_runner-1.6.1/bin/build_runner.dart:9:8: Error: Error when reading 'packages/args/command_runner.dart'

Comment: If you have problems using the Dart SDK, then you can contact Google for support. By the above link you can understand that I did not invent anything on my own.