# how to solve with a web dev server error in flutter for web?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

[edit]
if i run webdev serve in my project there appears

```
[WARNING] Throwing away cached asset graph because the build phases have changed. This most commonly would happen as a result of adding a new dependency or updating your dependencies.
[INFO] Cleaning up outputs from previous builds. completed, took 6.6s
[INFO] Building new asset graph completed, took 16.7s
[INFO] Checking for unexpected pre-existing outputs. completed, took 3ms
[INFO] Serving `web` on http://127.0.0.1:8080
[WARNING]build_web_compilers:entrypoint on web/main.dart: Skipping compiling retgoo_internal|web/main.dart with ddc because some of its
transitive libraries have sdk dependencies that not supported on this platform:

retgoo_internal|lib/protocol/http_non.dart

https://github.com/dart-lang/build/blob/master/docs/faq.md#how-can-i-resolve-skipped-compiling-warnings

[INFO] Running build completed, took 19.0s
[INFO] Caching finalized dependency graph completed, took 473ms
[INFO] Succeeded after 19.5s with 634 outputs (3522 actions)
```

but when I try to open in the browser just a blank page appears and when I try to start debugging there just launches and a blank page appears too. the launch didn't stop. there is a tutorial for the warning in the build.yaml file, but when I search for a lot of build.yaml files ... which file should I fix?

Comment: Maybe this answer will help you. https://stackoverflow.com/a/56818422/1737201

Comment: @mezone it'same, but the port is different like port:8082

Comment: if i use port:5416 its success but in browser appears "Could not find retgoo_internal/index.html or any files in retgoo_internal."

Comment: After you have edited your question, it looks completely different. Now it is a completely different question.

Answer (score 0):

In your wanrnig message it is clearly stated due to some transitive sdk dependencies the main.dart is not compiled.

> [WARNING]build_web_compilers:entrypoint on web/main.dart: Skipping compiling retgoo_internal|web/main.dart with ddc because some of its
>   transitive libraries have sdk dependencies that not supported on this platform:
>
> retgoo_internal|lib/protocol/http_non.dart

This simply means that none of your flutter related dart code is compiled to javascript.  In my limited knowledge, flutter-web does this.

1. It compiles yout dart code written using flutter framework into javascript.
2. This means main.dart and other dart files compiled into main.dart.js and other chunks.js files.
3. Then in the web/index.html this javascript file is loaded, which further creates and handles the new dom elements to be rendered in you page. Some thing like a Single Page Applications created by react or angular.

Once you fix the transitive dependencies in your pubspec.yaml which could have been introduced by any additional libraries you added as depencies, this problem wil be resolved.

Since flutter-web doesn't support any plugins yet this has to be done manually by pulling the sources for the plugins you wish to include, place along your source directories and change the import statements inside them from package:flutter/ to package:flutter_web. This is not trivial but still achievable.